# App crashes with react-native-beacons-manager

Tags: react-native, beacon

I was trying to use this library https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager in my project but the app crashes exactly with the method `startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region)`. I'm using React Native 0.62.5

My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

My build.gradle

```
buildscript {
  ext {
      buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
      minSdkVersion = 16
      compileSdkVersion = 28
      targetSdkVersion = 28
      supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I finally solve the problem trying this

https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager/issues/147#issuecomment-548567823

But for me doesn't work the fisrt step I just keep the 1.0.7 version in my project. I hope to help someone else :)